# ROCm and CUDA together in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, keras

is it possible to use ROCm together with CUDA GPUs on the same model in Keras? I dont think so since you need to have a different tf version for the both? Did anybody try to run it on different GPU's?

Comment: The answer is in your question, you need different TF version so its not possible now. Maybe in the future when ROCm is integrated in TF.

Comment: Ah yes, you asked this question before, please do not duplicate your own questions.